# using an external jar file in an ant build.xml file

Tags: ant

I'm totally new with `Ant`, and I don't know how `classpath` works in `Ant`. I have wrote a `Java` class to do some scripting for me, and I wanted to deploy it as a `task` in `Ant`. The class uses `commons-codec-1.2.jar` as an external library, in other to do some `Unicode` and `MD5` tasks for me. I've posted my `build.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <project name="TcZip" basedir="." default="jar">

    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="classes" />
    <property name="library.dir" value="library" />

    <path id="external.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${library.dir}/commons-codec-1.2.jar" />
    </path>

    <target name="clean" description="Delete all generated files">
    <delete dir="classes" />
    <delete file="TcZip.jar" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="Compiles the task">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="classes" />
        <classpath>
            <path refid="external.classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" description="JARs the Task" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="TcZip.jar" basedir="classes" />
    </target>

    <target name="use" description="Use the task" depends="jar">
    <taskdef name="tczip" classname="ZipComparision" classpath="${ant.project.name}.jar" />
    <tczip />
    </target>

</project>
```

In my `task` directory, I have :

```
+task
 - build.xml
 - classes
 - library
 - src
```

`library` and `classes` contain the `commons-codec-1.2.jar` file. However, as seen in the `build.xml` file I have added a `<property>` tag for the `library`.
When I execute `ant compile` I get:

```
compile:
    [javac] C:\workspace\task\build.xml:19: warning: 'includeantr
untime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for rep
eatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\workspace\task\classes

    [javac] C:\workspace\task\src\Tczip.java:18: error: package o
rg.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] C:\workspace\task\src\Tczip.java:190: error: cannot f
ind symbol
    [javac]     mdEnc = new String( Hex.encodeHex( digest ));
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable Hex
    [javac]   location: class Tczip
    [javac] C:\workspace\task\src\Tczip.java:254: error: cannot f
ind symbol
    [javac]          mdEnc = new String( Hex.encodeHex( digest ));
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable Hex
    [javac]   location: class Tczip
    [javac] 3 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\task\build.xml:19: Compile failed; see the compiler
error output for details.
```

Could someone please help me with that? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `location` in `pathelement` directive with `path`.

Comment: @philippe can you open the jar and see whether the file named Hex.class is present?

Comment: Yes, I was executing it nicely in `Eclipse` ( added the `jar` file to the `classpath` ), but I had to write this `Ant` build, and I don't know how to set up the `jar` file with the `Ant classpath`.

Comment: `<classpath refid="external.classpath"/>` instead

Comment: `javac` tag is not closed. it should be closed inside target. you are closing it before classpath directive

Comment: Now I had another problem, could you help me out?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17960/discussion-between-amareswar-and-philippe)